# Is there a penalty for Enumerable.ToList()

Tags: c#, linq

An Enumerable does not let us access elements by index like `anEnumerable[i]`. But a list does - `aList[i]`.  Therefore a List provides an extra feature compared to Enumerable.

When we perform .ToList() to convert an enumerable to a list, is the operation done in constant time or does it need to traverse the enumerable to be able to convert it to a list?

Comment: How could it create the list *without* traversing it?

Comment: Doesn't `IEnumerable<T>` implement `ElementAt(int index)`;?

Comment: @Silvermind: Not itself, no - that's an extension method... and it could be *very* expensive to call repeatedly, as due to the lazy nature of LINQ it could easily end up performing the query N times.

Comment: This may be helpful. [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 20 - ToList - By Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-20-tolist.aspx)

Comment: @Habib: Thanks - I was just trying to find that precise post :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw you're right, it can't. I would hope it doesn't enumerate when doing Array.ToList() though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I was not sure about it being a LINQ extension and I agree on it being expensive in almost every situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Time has to be at least O(n), since the code will be doing something like this:

```
public static IList<T> ToList(this IEnumerable<T> e)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    foreach (T elem in e) list.Add(elem);
    return list;
}
```

Since you have `list.Count` calls to Add, there's your cost.

I should point out that there is probably code in the more general case to do things like

```
if (e is IList<T>) return (IList<T>)e;
```

Comment: Firstly, `ToList` returns `List<T>`, not `IList<T>`. Secondly, there *isn't* an optimization if it's already a list to return the existing reference - it *always* creates a new `List<T>`. However, it can do that more efficiently if it's an `IList<T>`.

Comment: Well what the hell, Jon? Aren't we supposed to return the most generalized type that represents type?  Grumble, grumble, hypocrites at MS grumble.

Comment: Not always, no. Sometimes that's the right approach, but not always. Note that `ToDictionary` does the same thing, in terms of returning the concrete class rather than the interface.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at [ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it lets you pass in an index to look for, and will evaluate the enumerable up to that point.

Comment: That's fine if you're only going to call it once. If you're going to call it multiple times, it's almost certainly a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

`ToList()` enumerates through the IEnumerable one time and copies the items into a `List` object, so the complexity is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

It's at least an O(n) operation. `ToList()` forces enumeration of the `IEnumerable` meaning you iterate over the collection once. It most likely allocated a new list before that then adds each item a in a `foreach`.